# starter template custom page header issue

Tags: themes, templates, block-editor, page-template, headers

I am a beginner in WordPress and I am creating a website using a starter template.

The pages of the starter template have a background header but when I create a new page it is not showing as the page starter theme comes with.

See this is about us page which comes with the starter template I have used
[image]
now this is the gallery page that I created
[image]
see the menu above the page title block

How can I adjust this?